# How to find the proportion of k-NN neighbors that belong to a predicted class?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I want to plot a ROC curve for a k-NN clasifier, in Python. I have a dataset composed of 40 samples that are described by 5 features and the number of neighbors for k-NN is K = 7.

20 samples are used for training and 20 samples for testing. There are two possible predicted classes: "signal present" and "signal absent" (binary classification).

According to this [article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6af3/4ec6a8899f7316cb2b5f731b3db0412f7e10.pdf), to make the ROC curve for the k-NN classifier, a score can be defined as the proportion of the K neighbors that belong to the “signal present” class, and the threshold needed to classify a test instance in the “signal present” class is the number of neighbors varied from 1 to K.

**My question is how to find the proportion of K neighbors that belong to the “signal present” class?** I know the total number of neighbors (K = 7) and for calculating the proportion, I need to know the number of neighbors that belong to that class.

I've seen that there is a function [KNeighbors()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors), that returns the indices of and distances to the neighbors of a point, but how do I know which of the neighbors belong to the “signal present” class?

Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I've tried the following:

1. For the given test sample, find the K neighbors' indices using the kneighbors() function.
2. Count the number of neighbors belonging to the "signal present" class by checking the value of y_train[indices[i,0]] in a for loop (y_train results from the train_test_split() function).
3. Compare the number of neighbors to a threshold value.

Can someone confirm if I am proceeding correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue!! ✌️Dude don't ask for help while Google can solve your problem. If this solved your problem, then .